# How to enable Dell Laptop HDMI output? I can't seem to see the HDMI output at all

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a Dell Latitude 5400 laptop with Windows 10 (Pro) which has a HDMI output. Using a HDMI->DVI-D adaptor I have connected this to a monitor (BenQ senseye 3, model GL2460). The idea is to be use the monitor as well (or at least instead of) as the laptop's inbuilt monitor.

However, the monitor cannot pick up any signal from the laptop.

Looking in the Device Manager, I can't seem to see the HDMI output at all. (The "Display Adaptors" section just has "Microsoft Basic Display Adaptor" which I'm assuming to be the laptop's built-in display)

If, in Windows Settings / System / Display, I press the "Detect" button for "Multiple Displays" I get "Didn't detect another display".

When I plug in the monitor's cable, the monitor displays "No Signal Detected" (as opposed to "No Cable Connected" when it's plugged out) so at least the monitor knows it's plugged into something, just not receiving any signal.

How can I enable the HDMI output on the laptop?

---

**Update**: I found a button on the laptop (<kbd>F8</kbd> without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> - turns out it's the same as <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) which supposedly projects to another screen. However I got the following error:

> The PC cannot project to another screen, try reinstalling driver or using a different video card

So changing video card not being an option, I installed [the drivers found here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/product-support/product/latitude-14-5400-laptop/drivers).

Now I press the same button and I do get a menu on the right of the screen: "PC Screen Only", "Duplicate", "Extend", "Second Screen Only".

However nothing happens when I click on any of these (except that my selection is highlighted). There doesn't appear to be an "OK" button or anything like that to confirm my choice.

Comment: Display connectors do not show up in Device Manager. Did you reboot after installing the graphics driver? Did you check the Windows Display settings yet? There’s a “Detect” button. // Please provide your monitor’s exact model number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct graphics driver. "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" indicates that there's no graphics driver installed.

You should be able to [find the driver here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-14-5400-laptop/drivers).

Comment: What does the Device Manager show after you installed the graphics driver?

Comment: "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620"

Comment: Try to change display outputs with Display Settings (right click on Desktop) or via Intel Graphics Command Center.

Comment: Display Settings just brings me to the same place as Settings / System / Display. Intel Graphics Command Center also can't detect the connected monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a Dell Inspiron 5xxx on windows 11 (which is not supported by Dell, even though the hardware meets the minimum specs for windows 11).

The solution was to install the Intel Drivers, rather than the outdated ones provided by Dell - no surprise here.

The driver pack for can be downloaded from here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/96551/graphics/intel-hd-graphics-family/intel-hd-graphics-620.html (select the **Drivers & Software** tab). I think the driver pack has the drivers for all intel embedded video cards, but this could change in the future.